# Resetting animation effect on scroll, using jquery

Tags: jquery

I've made an effect where sections of a page fade in and move up slightly as the page scrolls down and they move onto the screen.

It only works the first time, however. I'm trying to dynamically reset the CSS to the initial properties when sections drop back down off the screen, so that it works every time you scroll down, but it's not resetting.

```
$(window).scroll( function(){

    $('section').each( function(i){

        var top_of_section = $(this).offset().top;
        var bottom_of_window = $(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() + 100;

        if( bottom_of_window > top_of_section ){

            $(this).animate({'opacity':'1', 'margin-top':'0'},500);

        } else if(bottom_of_window < top_of_section){
                $(this).css("opacity", "0");
                $(this).css("margin-top", "100px");        
       }

    }); 

});
```

Code pen here: https://codepen.io/tychus98/pen/yLNbZNW

How can I get it to reset?

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if I fully follow your question, but could this be the solution?
Here I've used CSS animations instead:

```js
$(window).scroll( function(){
    $('section').each( function(){
        const el               = $(this),
              top_of_section   = el.offset().top,
              bottom_of_window = $(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() + 100;

        if( bottom_of_window > top_of_section ) {
            el.addClass('slideItUp').removeClass('slideItDown');
        } else {
            el.addClass('slideItDown').removeClass('slideItUp');
        }
    }); 
});
```

```css
section{
  height: 100px;
  background-color: green;
  margin: 100px 0 20px;
  transition: margin linear 500ms, opacity linear 500ms;
}

.slideItDown {
  margin-top: 100px;
  opacity: 0;
}

.slideItUp {
  margin-top: 0;
  opacity: 1;
}

body{
  margin-bottom: 500px; 
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section>A</section>
<section>A</section>
<section>A</section>
<section>A</section>
<section>A</section>
<section>A</section>
<section>A</section>
<section>A</section>
<section>A</section>
<section>A</section>
<section>A</section>
<section>A</section>
<section>A</section>
<section>A</section>
<section>A</section>
<section>A</section>
<section>A</section>
<section>A</section>
<section>A</section>
<section>A</section>
<section>A</section>
<section>A</section>
<section>A</section>
<section>A</section>
```